# Why does rstan not recognise my variable?

Tags: r, rstan

I am using R 3.6.2 on Windows 10. I recently installed rstan (which by itself was a lot of trouble).

Rstan does not seem to recognise that I declared a variable.

My stan code:

```
data {
  int N;
  real Y[N];
}

parameters {
  real mu;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
}

model {
  for(i in 1:N)
   Y[i] ~ normal(mu, sigma);
  mu ~ normal(1.7,0.3);
  sigma ~ cauchy(0,1);
}
```

My r code:

```
#generate scenario data
N=as.integer(100)
set.seed(21)
Y=rnorm(N,1.6,0.2)
hist(Y)

# compile the model
library(rstan)
options(mc.cores=4) #set the number of CPU cores to be used for MC processing

model=stan_model("first_model.stan")

# move the data to stan and run the model
fit=sampling(model,list(N-N,Y-Y),iter=200,chains=1)
```

My r code produces the error:
"Error in new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) : 
  Exception: variable does not exist; processing stage=data initialization; variable name=N; base type=int  (in 'model336c6f43555f_first_model' at line 2)

failed to create the sampler; sampling not done"

Does anyone know why that is, or how to fix this? If I can't get this practice problem working, I can't even start my assignment due Tuesday.  :(

Comment: What is `list(N-N,Y-Y)`? Don't you mean `list(N=N,Y=Y)`?

Comment: Our professor gave us this code as a practice to ensure that we correctly installed stan. I just made the change you suggested and it worked. I should tell the prof. Also, I don't think that comments can be marked as answers, so could you please list that as an answer so I can give you credit ?